# Runtime error 'Could not find a part of the path'

Tags: c#, io

I'm programming in c#, trying to read text from a file to create a map for a game that I'm making, but for some reason I keep getting the following error:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'F:\TiledLevel01\TiledLevel01\bin\x86\Debug\Content\Map.txt'.

Can anyone tell me where I may be going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This says that the file you are trying to read does not exist. Are you sure that this file exists at exact this place?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not".
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably that file exists in your project, so highlight the file in `Solution Explorer`, hit <kbd>F4</kbd>, and set its `Build Action` to `Content`. That will copy the file to the output folder on build.